# How to create ASC/DESC indexes using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have the following table declaration

```
from gino import Gino

db = Gino()

class DatasetUpdateModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "dataset_updates"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    dataset_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True))

    __table_args__ = (
        db.Index(
            "dataset_updates_dataset_id_created_at_idx",
            "dataset_id",
            "created_at",
        ),
    )
```

I need to create the following index:

CREATE INDEX ON dataset_updates(dataset_id, created_at DESC);

How can I specify `DESC` order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of referring to the columns as strings, refer to them as their actual (object) references and add the `.desc()` modifier as required:

```py
    __table_args__ = (
        db.Index(
            "dataset_updates_dataset_id_created_at_idx",
            dataset_id,
            created_at.desc(),
        ),
    )
```